# Laravel 5 - Binding model from query string

Tags: php, laravel, binding, model, routes

I have the following URL:

`/search?customer=my-customer-slug&q=foo`

I wonder if there is a way to bind a `Customer` model into `$request->customer`, by searching from the `Customer's` slug.

Doing that when the URL is `/search/{customer-slug}` is very easy, but I don't know if I can do that with query strings.

Answer (score 2):

Although I don't see the advantage over using `/search/{customer-slug}`, you could use a middleware to achieve this.

Make a middleware to check for `customer` in the query string and assign it to the request. Then, you can attach this middleware to any route you expect to have a `customer` in the url.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Customer;
use Closure;

class CustomerQueryStringMiddleware
{

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure                 $next
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        if ($request->filled('customer')) {

            $customer = Customer::where('slug', $request->customer)->firstOrFail();

            $request->merge(['customer' => $customer]);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great @Hamoud. I'm not looking for an advantage, I was only wondering if there were a way to do so.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can do it with `query strings` with the below way:

```
if ($request->has('customer')) {
    $user->customer = $request->input('customer');
}
```

Comment: This is not binding the request parameter to Customer, you know?

Comment: he wants to access the value of customer parameter from URL in function /search?customer=my-customer-slug&q=foo